# Android: Notification - How to append addActionMethod to object using for cycle?

Tags: android, for-loop, notifications, cycle

I have the following method from helper which is set simple notification:

```
public void addNotification(final Class<? extends Activity> activityToOpen,
                                String contentTitle, String contentText,
                                Integer contentIcon, Boolean isCancelable,
                                ArrayList<NotificationButton> notificationButtonArrayList) {

        // prepare intent which is triggered if the
        // notification is selected
        Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, activityToOpen);
        // use System.currentTimeMillis() to have a unique ID for the pending intent
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

        // build notification
        // the addAction re-use the same intent to keep the example short
        Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(mCtx)
                .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setSmallIcon(contentIcon)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_drawer, "Call", pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_drawer, "More", pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_drawer, "And more", pIntent).build();

        // Complete add action and append to object
        for (Integer i=0; i < notificationButtonArrayList.size(); i++) {
            notificationButtonArrayList.get(i);
            NotificationButton nb = notificationButtonArrayList.get(i);
            //addAction(nb.getIcon(), nb.getText(), nb.getIntent());
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, n);
    }
```

I would like to avoid part of code which is containing definition for the notification buttons:

```
.addAction(R.drawable.ic_drawer, "Call", pIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_drawer, "More", pIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_drawer, "And more", pIntent)
```

And i would like to append this addAction method in the for cycle which is containing values to pass into the **addAction** method.

I would like to ask, how can i do it using the for cycle (or anything else)?

Many thanks for any advice.